# can we unregister old service worker by its name and register new service worker

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

I am facing some problem related to service worker before some time i am using gcm and service worker file name was service-worker.js after releasing fcm i changed my code and now my service worker file name is firebase-messaging-sw.js but in some my client browser calling old service-worker.js file which is generating an error(service-worker.js not found 500). I already used following code before gettoken().

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
.then((registration) => {
  messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

  // Request permission and get token.....
});
```

but its still showing this error.

Comment: I resolved it. I create one more file similar to firebase-messaging-sw.js and rename it to my old service worker file service-worker.js.
    
    Now, when browser call my old service worker file that is service-worker.js then its works same as firebase-messaging-sw.js that is my new file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have multiple service workers registered with different scopes, and you want to get a list of them from a client page (and potentially unregister some of them, based on either matching scope or SW URL), you can do the following:

```
async unregisterSWs({matchingScope, matchingUrl}) {
  const registrations = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations();
  const matchingRegistrations = registrations.filter(registration => {
    if (matchingScope) {
      return registration.scope === matchingScope;
    }

    if (matchingUrl) {
      return registration.active.scriptURL === matchingUrl;
    }
  });

  for (const registration of matchingRegistrations) {
    await registration.unregister();
    console.log('Unregistered ', registration);
  }
}
```

and then call it passing in either a scope or SW script URL that you want to use to unregister:

```
unregisterSWs({matchingScope: 'https://example.com/push'});
unregisterSWs({matchingUrl: 'https://example.com/my-push-sw.js'});
```